# Error : ! File ended while scanning use of \textit

Tags: compilation-error

I'm new to Latex and I have a problem with my code : everytime I try to compile it, it shows the same error :

> ! File ended while scanning use of \textit .
> inserted text
> \par
> l.61 \input{retranscription devoir.tex}
> I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
> to read past where you wanted me to stop.

I tried to see where I could have forgotten an '{' but I can't seem to find it.
was wondering if you could help me solve this problem.
Also, there is no problem with the files attached, i compiled it before and it worked. It only stopped working when i added the index section.
Here is my code (I only put it until line 61 since it seems that the issue happened before that) :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openany]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,main=french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[marginal,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}
        \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[alph]
        \DeclareNewFootnote{B}[arabic]
        \renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{(\alph{footnoteA})}
        
\newcommand{\marge}{(\textit{Dans la marge:})~}


\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}

%Initpers is used  when the name of a person is first used in the text
\makeindex[name=noms, title=Index nominum, columns=2]
\newcommand{\initpers}[3]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{#3 #2}{#1}
    }


\newcommand{\pers}[1]{#1\index{#1@#1}}


\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\textsc{\Large{University}}\\[2 cm]
\textsc{\large{\'{E}dition de données}}\\[1.5 cm]
\LARGE{\bfseries{Documents}}
\bigbreak
\bigbreak
\bigbreak
\bigbreak
      \large{E}\textsc{Pro}\\[3 cm]   
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Logo Séoul 1988.jpg}    

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\section*{Retranscription}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Retranscription}

\input{retranscription devoir.tex}
```

Comment: You probably have a blank line in the argument of `\textit`.

Comment: Welcome TeX.SE. What happens if you eliminate the whitespace in the filename (and in the argument of `\input`?

Comment: The issue seems to be inside `retranscription devoir.tex`, which you haven't shown.

Comment: note that size commands do not take an argument. `\large{E}` is the same as `\large E` and will make the rest of the document (or here, the rest of the `center`) large. Similarly `\bfseries` does not take an argument. `\LARGE{\bfseries{Documents}}` should be `{\LARGE{\bfseries  Documents}}`

Comment: Thank you for all the answers ! It seems that the issue was indeed in the retranscription file but i also modified the code with your suggestions.